# invalid hex number ora-01465

Tags: spring, oracle, jsf-2, file-io

i have this query in my code. i am trying to isert a image into table in the last column(blob). it is showing invalid hex number. can anybody help me out of this?

```
 @ManagedBean(name="userprofile",eager=true)
 @SessionScoped
 public class Profile {

 @ManagedProperty("#{jdbcTemplate}")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private String firstName,lastName,email,description;
    private UploadedFile photo1;
    private int contactNumber;
private String insertQry;


public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
    public UploadedFile getPhoto1() {
return photo1;
    }

    public void setPhoto1(UploadedFile photo1) {
 this.photo1 = photo1;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
     }

    public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getContactNumber() {
return contactNumber;
    }

     public void setContactNumber(int contactNumber) {
  this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
     }

     public void insertProfile() throws Exception{

 InputStream is=photo1.getInputstream();
 System.out.println(is);
 insertQry="insert into profile   
               values('"+getFirstName()+"','"+getLastName()+"','"+getContactNumber()+"',
               '"+getEmail()+"','"+getDescription()+"','"+utl_raw.cast_to_raw(is)+"')";
 System.out.println(insertQry);



int num=jdbcTemplate.update(insertQry);
System.out.println(num);

   }

   }
```

any  kind of response is  appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
 invalid hex number ora-01465
```

means that your not sending an Hexa.

**Solution:**

Please try to convert `InputStream` to `Hexa` before insert image.